# Three.js Blender Exports With No Materials

Tags: json, three.js, blender

When I export model as a .json file from blender (a model with materials applied) the resulting file has no material applied.

In the Three drop down menu, each material is set to NormalBlending, Enable depth writing is checked,and enable depth testing is checked.

Again the .josn file has no metadata, and no materials applied to it. See code sample below. (please can you help me) I really need to get this project finished. I have been trying for 3 solid days now.

When I export model as a .json file from blender (a model with materials applied) the resulting file has no material applied.

In the Three drop down menu, each material is set to NormalBlending, Enable depth writing is checked,and enable depth testing is checked.

Again the .josn file has no metadata, and no materials applied to it. See code sample below. (please can you help me) I really need to get this project finished. I have been trying for 3 solid days now.
Link to a sample of the code showing empty metadata and material data --> http://pastebin.com/ZwcaJz5L

```
{    
  "textures": [],
  "materials": [],
  "images": [],
  "metadata": {
    "generator": "io_three",
    "version": 4.3,
    "sourceFile": "cfc_gui_def_green.blend",
    "type": "Object"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't recreate this. The pastebin is only a partial JSON and not too useful in this context. The exporter creates a log in your $TMPDIR. A shell window prints the log path

`Log: /var/folders/0s/d7365qbn5gv76sj266_9qqs00000gn/T/io_three.export.log`

That is a bit more informative and without the actual scene the log is possibly the only thing that may help (if it even logged anything that may indicate the problem). Never had an issue with missing materials (note that there is a difference between "materials" and "face materials") so there isn't much to go on here.

Comment: The empty "materials" array does show me the "Materials" option was selected but it can't seem to find any materials on your nodes. This is odd because there is no real magic here, each object has a materials list to iterate on to be the JSON array so it isn't clear where the disconnection is at.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying in my temp dir in windows I will find a folder called var and if I follow the path above I will find a log file?

Comment: Not quite, that path is on my machine. Your operating system will have a different path, it prints in the shell window.

Comment: Either the log or share the .blend scene

Comment: Also here is a link to the blender model and the latests .json export that I posted in Pastebin http://lilsamedia.com/three_js_blender/

Comment: I am looking at your options and see that materials is False, example:

` 'skinning': False, 'morphTargets': False})`

This would indicate that the "Materials" checkbox is not checked.

Comment: I got the materials when selecting the "Materials" check box. I have materials in my JSON (pastebin is acting up at the moment)

Comment: Sorry what checkbox.. I am sorry to sound so stupid.. I see two checkbixes under the "Three" dropdown enable depth writing, and Enable depth testing. Both are checked

Comment: Do you mean the materials utils in the addons?

Comment: The export options, not the materials options. There is a "Materials" section that has options for Materials, Face Materials, UVs, etc. You need to check on correct options there http://i.imgur.com/wu0jFYX.png

Comment: And when I say "the materials options" I meant the parameters on the material nodes themselves. The export options are for the entire export, the material node parameters are specific to certain attributes on a per-material basis.

Comment: I feel so stupid.. I am a C4D guy and there is no .json export options (why I have no idea) so I had to try to learn Blender. for this project.

Comment: Well nobody has written a C4D exporter. Not that I am a Blender fanboy but I will say that the Blender exporter is probably the best supported exporter you're going to find (for now at least). Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am still having issues trying to see my model in my project window (they just dont show up). I am trying to replace existing .json models in a configurator gui. My files seem a little different than the ones I see in the "models" asset folder. I realize this problem is not with in the scope of this problem. Would it be possible to talk to you in a side bar about what I am running into?  If not I totally understand.

Comment: I am sometimes around IRC tho if you see me there it does not always mean I am immediately available.

Answer (score 3):

The Final answer to my problem was I did not have the "Materials" check box selected in the Three_js The export options, not the materials options. repsac is the one that helped me, I dont know how to vote for him, or highlight his comment above with the link as being the correct answer. This is my first time here, so I am trying to define the answer that corrected my problem, and give credit to repsac for being the person who helped me with the correct information. I'd be happy to edit my posts to do it correctly if someone wants to tell me how. Thanks repsac for your help, you sir are the man. AKf